# Decoding SWIFT model class from text file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parsing, nsscanner

I have a model class

```
class User{
var name:String
var number:Int
}
```

i have the details of this downloaded as a text file with format

```
firstname:John
rollnumber:234
```

5

How can i right a custom decorder for this.

NB: the keys 'firstname' 'rollnumber' are dynamic and are obtained from backend.

Comment: It's not JSON, right? You can use `components(separatedBy:)` to get lines (with a new line `CharacterSet`), then again ` components(separatedBy:)` with the ":" separator, and then instantiate your object.

Answer (score 0):

Parse like this, pass the response as `Dict` to the `init` method

```
class User{
var name:String?
var number:Int?
   init(With dict:[String:Any]){
     if let value = dict["firstname"] as? String{
       name = value
     }
     if let value = dict["rollnumber"] as? Int{
       number = value
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: note: format of response isn't even dictionary convertible

Answer (score 0):

Would be something like this:

```
struct User: Decodable {

    let name: String
    let number: Int

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: UserKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        number = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .number)
    }

    private enum UserKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "firstname"
        case number = "rollnumber"
    }


    static getUser(jsonData: Data) -> User? {
        do {
            let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from:jsonData)
            return user
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
   }

}
```

And get user:

```
User.getUser(jsonData: data)
```

Comment: to even reach this step the data should be of a valid json